# Adding values dynamically to a drop down from mysql database using jsp

Tags: jquery, jsp, servlets, drop-down-menu

I need help in adding the values to a drop down dynamically from mysql database.

**Work Flow:**

In my jsp page,

1.Country name is a session attribute from a servlet

2.Sate is an autocomplete text box

3.District is a drop down.

Based on the country name the State text box will be filled through autocomplete and the district name is a drop down where the district names should be added  to the drop down dynamically

**Issue:**

I need to add the values of the district names into my drop down list based on the location and the state.

My db query is `"Select district from locationlist where country='"+country+"'and state='"+state+"'";`

Here in the 'where' condition the country and the state values should be passed from my jsp page.

Kindly help me in adding the values to the drop down menu present in my jsp page(Location.jsp),based on my requirements.

This is my code

**Location.jsp**

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Location</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/style1.css" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="JS/jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>
<script>
     jQuery(function(){
            $("#state").autocomplete("Statelist.jsp");
      });
</script>  
<script type="text/javascript">        
        function addRow(tableID) {

            var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

            var rowCount = table.rows.length;
            var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

            var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;

            for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {

                var newcell = row.insertCell(i);

                newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[1].cells[i].innerHTML;
                //alert(newcell.childNodes);
                switch(newcell.childNodes[0].type) {
                    case "text":
                            newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";

                            jQuery(function(){
            $('input[name="state"]').autocomplete("Statelist.jsp");
                         });
                         break;

                    case "select-one":
                            newcell.childNodes[0].selectedIndex = 0;
                            break;
                }

            }

        }

        function deleteRow(tableID) {

            try {

            var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

       var rowDelete = table.rows.length - 1;

       if (rowDelete > 1)

           table.deleteRow(rowDelete);

       else

         alert("Cannot delete all the rows.")


            }
            catch(e) {
                alert(e);
            }
        }
    </script>


</head>

<body>

<h1><font face="Times New Roman" align="center">Form</font></h1><br/><br/>
<h5><font color="blue"> Country: <% String country=(String)session.getAttribute("country");
       out.print(country); %>  
       <c:set var="country" value="country" scope="session"  /></font> </h5>
<br/>
<div>
<center>
    <form>

      <input type="button" id="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('dataTable')"  />

    <input type="button" value="Delete Row" onclick="deleteRow('dataTable')" />
    <input type="button" value="Save"/>
    <br/>
    <br/>

     <table id="dataTable" align="center" width="350px" border="1">

   <tr>
        <th>State</th>
        <th>District</th>

    </tr>

    <tr>

   <td> <input type="text" class="auto" id="state" name="state"/></td> &nbsp;
    <td><select name="district"/>
    <option value="select">SELECT</option>
  </select>
    </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
</center>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.....put code snippet in while loop

```
<td><select name="district"/>
    <% while(rs.next()==true)
   {      
   %>
<option value=<%rs.getString("name");%>> <% rs.getString("name");%> </option>
<% } %>
```

Comment: In my code ,country is a session attribute and state is an autocomplete text box.These two are the inputs which I will be using in 'where' condition.Do I need to have my DB manipulations in a servlet code or in the same JSP (Location.jsp) page to add the values to my drop down ?

Comment: I am in a confusion ! Where do I need to have my JDBC part, in the same jsp page or do I need to create a servlet to handle the database?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to display a list in your JSP page

try this idea ( you must know that using scriplets in your JSP is discourged )

you say : I have a servlet to pass Country name is a session attribute 
you can do the same thing to pass a List to your JSP using the same servlet the way is :

1/ create a new serialisable java class where you put the 'district' attribute

```
public class MYBEAN  implements Serializable {

    private String district;


//ADD GETTER AN SETTER METHODS 

public MYBEAN() {



    }

public MYBEAN(String disctrict) {

        this.disctrict = disctrict;

    }


public List<MYBEAN> loadData(String state,String country)
    {
        List<MYBEAN> actorList = new ArrayList<BookData>();

        com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement ps = null;  




            ResultSet rs = null;  

             String url="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/DATABASENAME";//CHANGE
            String name="NAME";//CHANGE
            String pw="PWD";//CHANGE
            String driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";    


            Connection connexion=null;


try
{    
    Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
    connexion=DriverManager.getConnection(url,name,pw);        


    String q ="Select district from locationlist where country='"+country+"'and state='"+state+"'";
           Statement commande=connexion.createStatement();
              rs=commande.executeQuery(q);                 
               while (rs.next())
                {

MYBEAN bk = new MYBEAN(rs.getString("district"));/*CHANGE COLUMN NAMES*/

                actorList.add(bk);

                }


                return actorList;


                }catch(Exception e)
                {
                e.printStackTrace();

                return null;

                }
                finally
                {
                try
                {
                rs.close();
                connexion.close();

                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                e.printStackTrace();
                }
                }

    }

}
```

2/ You servlet

```
public class EXAMPLE_SERVLET extends HttpServlet {


    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

      String option= request.getParameter("country");
      String state= request.getParameter("state");

        MYBEAN dao = new MYBEAN();
        List<MYBEAN> list = dao.loadData( state, country);

        request.setAttribute("MYlist", list);

        RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("MY.jsp");
        view.forward(request, response); 

    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {



    }



}
```

3/ In your JSP ADD THIS CODE

```
<select name="database">
  <c:forEach items="${MYlist}" var="databaseValue">
    <option value="${databaseValue}">
        ${databaseValue}
    </option>
  </c:forEach>
</select>
```